# override css in a gnome shell extension with a shell theme

Tags: gnome, themes, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

Can css in a gnome-shell-extension be overridden by css in a shell theme?
E.g. "Dash to Panel" has the following lines in its stylesheet.css:

```
#dashtopanelScrollview .app-well-app:hover .overview-icon,
#dashtopanelScrollview .app-well-app:focus .overview-icon {
    background: none;
}

#dashtopanelScrollview .app-well-app:hover > :first-child,
#dashtopanelScrollview .app-well-app:focus > :first-child {
    background-color: rgba(238, 238, 236, 0.1);
}
```

When I place the same selectors or more specific selectors in my gnome-shell.css and try to change the background of .overview-icon, the css from Dash to Panel's stylesheet.css is used instead.

Answer (score 0):

Given the CSS you provided, I was able to force the styling by using the important rule.

```
#dashtopanelScrollview .app-well-app:hover .overview-icon,
#dashtopanelScrollview .app-well-app:focus .overview-icon {
    background: red!important;
}

#dashtopanelScrollview .app-well-app:hover > :first-child,
#dashtopanelScrollview .app-well-app:focus > :first-child {
    background-color: red!important;
}
```