# How can I change the background colour for the applications panel in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell

I do not know if that's the correct name for this panel, but I would like to change it to a blue colour, same as the desktop colour.

How to go about it? Thanks

edit:

i tried the suggestion at [How to change App Drawer background to be less transparent](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1090352/how-to-change-app-drawer-background-to-be-less-transparent)

to edit the gdm3.css file but after editing with new colour code and rebooting, the colour remains the same. are there other copies of the file in other directories being used beside /etc/alternatives/ ?

[image: background colour]

[image: shell theme]

[image: hot corners]

Comment: Try downloading the **Gnome Tweak Tool**: `sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool`.  I know you can change the application panel "Theme," but background color I'm not too sure about.

Comment: @lenovolobo i have checked it in default 18.04 also, it worked as expected.

Comment: @lenovolobo can you share your shell theme please.. https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUdTD.png

Comment: hello, i relooked the gdm3.css file and realised that line 1321 does not correspond to my /* App Vault/Grid */ which is at line 1213. after modifying the colour for that line, i rebooted but gnome shell cannot be started:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1095895/cannot-access-gnome-shell-after-editing-gdm3-css

so now i have 2 problems.

do you think it could be related to this:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034264/override-css-in-a-gnome-shell-extension-with-a-shell-theme

i have the mac os mojave dash to panel and dash to dock by unc926 installed. thanks

Comment: @lenovolobo if your shell theme is stored in `~/.themes/copernico-theme-v3.26/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css`. edit this file to get the required color.

Comment: @lenovolobo when you use different shell theme than default one, you should directly edit the file /usr/share/themes/copernico-theme-v3.26/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css. I have edited this file and the result is like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/02j9u.gif

Comment: i modified the file in ~/.themes/copernico-theme-v3.26/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css rebooted but still no change. then i copied the copernico-theme which was not present initially to /usr/share/themes/copernico-theme-v3.26/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css, rebooted but still no change

Comment: would it help to create a .gresource file as follows? :

https://www.devpy.me/the-best-linux-lockscreen/

Comment: @lenovolobo can you change your shell theme to default one and then edit it as per the Original Answer and see. Later we can find out why is it not applying to other themes in your case.